# Debian nfs-client shows nobody:nogroup

Tags: ldap, nfs

i have a running ldap-server, which works well with my webserver.
Now i tried to get the nfs-server running with my a MySQL server.
I (think) i did the same things like on my webserver configuration.

I created a new ldap-user `dbuser` and i can mount the directory from the NFS server.
On the NFS server itself, all files and directories are owned by `dbuser:db-users`.
If i look at the mounted directory on the MySQL server, all files and directories are owned by `nobody:nogroup`.

If i run getent passwd on the MySQL server, the ldap-user `dbuser` is shown, so i wonder, why this error happens.

Also: All servers are running the same OS, Debian `Wheezy`.

Comment: Please share the relevant lines from `/proc/mounts` on both clients.

Comment: …and the options that you're using in the /etc/exports file on the nfs server.